# How to create files named a001...a200 by using csh

Tags: csh

I would like to create 200 files having names formatting:

```
a001
a002
a003
...
a199
a200
```

My code does not work. It said, "Badly placed ()'s". Can you help me out?

```
#!/bin/csh
for (( i=1; i<201; i++ ))
do
    mkdir $(printf %03d $i)
done
```

Answer (score 2):

For a start, command substitution using `$()` is a `bash` feature (though it may be in some other shells as well). In `csh`, *backticks* are used for command substitution, so you would need (for creating *files* of the form `aNNN`, rather than directories):

```csh
touch `printf a%03d $i`
```

---

In any case, it's your `for` loop that's the immediate problem here. The `csh` shell has `foreach` and `while` loops so a generalised `for` loop is usually done like this:

```csh
foreach i (`seq 1 200`)
    touch `printf a%03d $i`
end
```

or:

```csh
@ i = 1
while ($i <= 200)
    touch `printf a%03d $i`
    @ i++
end
```

---

Of course, since you appear to be using `bash`-like commands, perhaps the easiest solution would be just to change the shebang line to the following :-)

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
```

This is especially a good idea since, while `csh` is a very good *interactive* shell, it doesn't really shine that much for programming. Don't get me wrong, you *can* write programs for it, it's just that other shells seem to have more ability.

Comment: I am not sure, The error 'Badly placed ()'s.' still appears. It may be "for" loop problem.

Comment: @BinhThien, that was a separate issue, now also included in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at this

```
#!/bin/csh
set i = 1
while ($i < 201)
    set j = `printf "a%03d" $i`
    touch $j
    @ i = $i + 1
end
```

The while command is the best loop available in csh. Setting the variable j to the output of the printf command is via the backtick ` .  then touch makes the file.
The @ command is what increments the loop.